# View PDF swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am working on Application which will display live PDF. Means whatever I will type it will be displayed in PDF. For that I am using webview to show PDF. Everytime after writing in textfield I am loading PDF in webview. So it is refreshed and blinking. It looks not so good. Is there any other option using which I can load PDF every time, but It will not blink. Please Help me to solve this. As I am new to this thing.

Thnaks..

Comment: instead of webview just take UITextView with user Interaction disabled & load the text every time you enter character.

Comment: As par my opinion you need to write a pdf manually as per your requerement and draw its layout then you can load it in webview. check this: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=write+a+pdf+in+swift&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=dznqVtnAC8vbuQSB8KSgDw

Comment: Actually I want to resume.. I have format of that... When I will enter name in textfield name will be shown in my pdf..

Comment: yes but for that you need to write and draw its formate. i shared a google link please check so you will get an idea.

Comment: Please download this git and check how its work https://github.com/thefredelement/Swift-PDFRenderer then learn it and apply as per your requirement.

Comment: I have used [SimplePDF](https://github.com/nRewik/SimplePDF) for generating PDF. Now I want to only show that PDF. Issue is blinking of PDF File every time

Comment: I have already created PDF files

Comment: when I am going from one textfield to another textfield, my first textfield's data is rendered in PDF.. but it is refreshed so user can fell that it is refreshed and it looks not so good

Comment: If you are looking for commercial solutions, there are plenty in the market that can help you achieve a better experience. https://pspdfkit.com/